# add event to fullcalendar by dropping from external source

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to add an event to the fullcalendar jquery plugin from an external source. I need the event title; start and end dates.  I read that the `drop` callback function is called when you drop an external source on the calendar.  This reports the start date in the alert.  The `eventReceive` option shows the title of the event.  This alert is displayed after the `drop` callback.  This is the code:

```
$('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar({
...
 droppable: true,
 drop: function(date) {
        alert("Dropped on " + date );
 },
eventReceive: function (event) {
         alert('event, ' + event.title + ', was added, (need date here)');
 },
```

How do I get the start date value from the `drop` callback to the `eventRecieve` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the start and end dates within the `drop` event.  This is the code I added to the `drop` event:

```
drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
    var memberName = $(this).data('event').title;
    var memberID = $(this).attr('id').toString();
    //Create Event - add to array
    var newEvent = new Object();
    newEvent = {
        title: memberName,
        id: memberID,
        start: date.format(),
        end: date.format(),
        objectID: 0
    };
    eventsAdded.push(newEvent);
},
```